# show this is that.. I can't work with matrix.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I have been working this question for a while, and got stuck for 1 hour so I decided to ask for help. This is maily due to my rusty math skill working with matrix.

$J(x_t) = \frac{1}{2}(x_t-x^*)^TP(x_t-x^*)$

where $P\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, P is positive definite, $a, x_t, x^* \in \mathbb R^n$, with $x^*$ fixed.

$$x_{t+1} = x_t - \frac{g_t^Tg_t}{g_t^TPg_t} g_t, $$ where $g_t = Px_t+a$.

Show that $J(x_{t+1}) = \left(1-\frac{(g^T_tg_t)^2}{(g_t^TPg_t)(g_t^TP^{-1}g_t)}\right)J(x_t)$.

Hint: Consider using $(J(x_t) - J(x_{t+1})) / (J(x_t)$.

---

**Attempt**:

I try to basically substitute $x_{t+1}$ onto J, expand it , and got some dirty equations and unable to make it the form they requre. I try to do the reverse direction as well, but I am not able to work my way out.

Comment: Could you clarify what is being divided in the expression $g_t^T g_t / (g_t^T P g_t)  g_t$? I presume you mean $\frac{g_t^T g_t}{g_t^T P g_t} g_t$?

Comment: Also, what is $h$?

Comment: yes, it is correct. not h, I meant J

Comment: I edited the question --- can you please confirm that I didn't destroy the intent of the question?

Comment: There are perhaps some typos or missing conditions in your question. As it stands, the hypothesis is false. E.g. when everything is a scalar, the hypothesis implies that
$$
(x_{t+1}-x^\ast)^TP(x_{t+1}-x^\ast)=J(x_{t+1})=\left(1-\frac{(g^T_tg_t)^2}{(g_t^TPg_t)(g_t^TP^{-1}g_t)}\right)J(x_t)=(1-1)J(x_t)=0
$$
and hence $x_{t+1}$ is necessarily equal to $x^\ast$. But this cannot be true because the definitions of $x_t,g_t$ and $x_{t+1}$ do not depend on $x^\ast$.